# Explanation for the relation of a metric tensor in a vector space and the metric function on topological spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors, tangent-bundle

I have always wondered, an it seems as I cannot figure it out on my own, the following.

Consider a differentiable manifold $M$ with a metric tensor $g$, which acts on tangent vectors at any point $p\in M $, now, obviously $g$ gives meaning to distances and angles in $M$, nevertheless $M$ is also a topological manifold, which is implies is second countable and Hausdorff, suppose it is also paracompact, then $M$ is indeed metrizable, which means there exists a map $d:M \times M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the following for any $x,y,z\in M$.

1. $d(x,y)\geq 0$, where the equality is satisfied if and only if $x=y$
2. $d(x,y)=d(x,y)$
3. $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\geq d(x,z)$

This map is called the distance function or metric (which makes me uncomfortable). My question is:

> Is there a natural way to induce $d$ from $g$ or the converse?

Comment: Yes. You can find this in any reasonable book on differential geometry. Given $g$, you define the metric space structure by $d(x,y)  = \inf\{\text{length}(\gamma): \gamma \text{ a piecewise-smooth curve from $x$ to $y$}\}$. Of course, the length of a curve is computed using $g$. The topology is induced by this metric is equivalent to the original manifold topology. (See, among other things, the Hopf-Rinow Theorem.) You cannot in general go in the other direction.

Comment: By piecewise-smooth do you mean that the set of points in which $\gamma$ is not smooth has measure zero?

Comment: Also, in what conditions is it possible to go in the other direction, can you give some reference to where could I get some more information about this?

Comment: No, piecewise-smooth means that there are finitely many points where $\gamma$ fails to be (at least) $C^1$. The other direction is very complicated and I don't know a good answer; but, for starters, how do you know your metric space is even a differentiable manifold?

Comment: Obviously, thinking you have a differentiable manifold, which is metric. Can I construct a metric tensor?

Comment: Not every distance function on a manifold corresponds to a metric tensor. Even if we restrict to distance functions which generate the same topology, the answer is still no if I recall correctly.